# How do you delete different scenes in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

For my program, I am trying to create a multiple choice game.

I want to get delete a scene in the code. This includes the difficulty screen.

Difficulty Screen:

[image]

Below shows the relevant parts of my code.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
import pygame.freetype
import random

X = 1275
Y = 775
green = (50, 205, 50)
blue = (0, 0, 205)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((X,Y))
font100 = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 100)


class SimpleScene:
   FONT = None

   def __init__(self, next_scene, *text):
       self.background = pygame.Surface((1275, 775))
       self.background.fill(pygame.Color('white'))

       y = 200
       if text:
           if SimpleScene.FONT == None:
               SimpleScene.FONT = pygame.freetype.SysFont(None, 32)
           for line in text:
               SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(self.background, (220, y), line, pygame.Color('black'))
               SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(self.background, (220, y - 1), line, pygame.Color('black'))
               y += 50

       self.next_scene = next_scene
       self.additional_text = None

   def start(self, text):
       self.additional_text = text

   def draw(self, screen):
       screen.blit(self.background, (0, 0))
       if self.additional_text:
           y = 180
           for line in self.additional_text:
               SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(screen, (120, y), line, pygame.Color('black'))
               SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(screen, (119, y - 1), line, pygame.Color('white'))
               y += 50

   def update(self, events, dt):
       for event in events:
           if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
               if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                   return (self.next_scene, None)


class GameState:
   def __init__(self, difficulty):
       self.difficulty = difficulty

   def pop_question(self):
       q = self.questions[0]
       self.current_question = q
       return q

class SettingScene:

   def __init__(self):
       self.background = pygame.Surface((1275, 775))
       self.background.fill(pygame.Color('white'))

       if SimpleScene.FONT == None:
           SimpleScene.FONT = pygame.freetype.SysFont(None, 32)

       SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(self.background, (120, 50), 'Select your difficulty level', pygame.Color('black'))
       SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(self.background, (119, 49), 'Select your difficulty level', pygame.Color('black'))

       self.rects = []

       # CHANGE
       for n in range(4):
           rect = pygame.Rect(50, (n * 70) + 100, 500, 50)
           self.rects.append(rect)

   def start(self, *args):
       pass

   def draw(self, screen):
       screen.blit(self.background, (0, 0))
       n = 1
       for rect in self.rects:
           if rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
               pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.Color('darkgrey'), rect)
           pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.Color('darkgrey'), rect, 5)

           # CHANGE
           SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(screen, (rect.x + 30, rect.y + 15), str(n), pygame.Color('black'))
           SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(screen, (rect.x + 29, rect.y + 14), str(n), pygame.Color('black'))

           n += 1

   def update(self, events, dt):
       for event in events:
           if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
               n = 1
               for rect in self.rects:
                   if rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                       return ('GAME', GameState(n))
                   n += 1

class GameScene:
   def __init__(self):
       if SimpleScene.FONT == None:
           SimpleScene.FONT = pygame.freetype.SysFont(None, 32)

       self.rects = []

       for n in range(4):
           rect = pygame.Rect(420, (n * 70) + 300, 500, 50)
           self.rects.append(rect)

   def start(self, gamestate):
       self.background = pygame.Surface((1275, 775))
       self.background.fill(pygame.Color('white'))


   def draw(self, screen):
       screen.blit(self.background, (0, 0))

       n = 0
       for rect in self.rects:
           if rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
               pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.Color('darkgrey'), rect)
           pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.Color('darkgrey'),
                            rect, 5)


   def update(self, events, dt):
       for event in events:
           if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
               n = 1
               for rect in self.rects:
                   if rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                       self.gamestate.answer(n)




class QuitScene:
   def __init__(self):
       if SimpleScene.FONT == None:
           SimpleScene.FONT = pygame.freetype.SysFont(None, 32)

   def start(self, gamestate):
       self.background = pygame.Surface((1275, 775))
       self.background.fill(pygame.Color('white'))
       self.gamestate = gamestate

   def draw(self, screen):
       screen.blit(self.background, (0, 0))

   def update(self, events, dt):
       for event in events:
           if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
               quit()


def main():
   pygame.init()
   screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1275, 775))
   clock = pygame.time.Clock()
   dt = 0

   scenes = {
       'TITLE': SimpleScene('SETTING', 'You have chosen category 1: Introduction to Programming ', '', '', '', 'press [SPACE] to start'),
       'SETTING': SettingScene(),
       'GAME': GameScene(),
       'QUIT': QuitScene(),
   }
   scene = scenes['TITLE']
   while True:
       events = pygame.event.get()
       for e in events:
           if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
               return

       game = scene.update(events, dt)
       if game:
           next_scene, state = game
           if next_scene:
               scene = scenes[next_scene]
               scene.start(state)


       scene.draw(screen)

       pygame.display.flip()
       dt = clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

If there is any solution to deleting this scene, please do share. I have tried may ways to delete parts of the code but nothing works. Thank you.

Comment: In this case, specify wich part of the code I have to delete or change. Tell me more precisely.

Comment: @fkS124 So if you run the algorithm, you will see the different scenes that pop up. The images are in the question which is what I want to delete. I’m thinking that the “select your difficulty screen” is under the class SettingScene. And the result screen at the end is under the class GameState where it begins with def get_result. I’m not sure how to delete it correctly because when I run it there’s usually errors.

Comment: Usually, errors show a path to where the error is located you should click on this path and see what's going on and what type of error it is. Notice me if you want me to debug your script.

Comment: You should maybe remove this scene directly in the dict containing all scenes in your main function. The one named `'SETTINGS'` is maybe the good one. Try with all scenes you've got in this dict so you can easily say what scenes is designed for.

Comment: If I remove 'SETTINGS' from this script, I can't press the space bar to begin the script if I run it. Have you tried testing my code? I think if you test it, you will understand what I mean.

Comment: Copy, i'll test it right now

Comment: I'm really sorry mate, I ran out of my brain's energy, I can't understand what you are trying to do ! You are using such a difficult way to do that properly ! 

And obviously, I can't run your code with all these syntax errors.

Try an easier way to do it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To "remove" the old screen you have to fill the whole screen with a color. That's how `Pygame` handles that, and you are already doing that, when you call `self.background.fill(pygame.Color('white'))` on each `start` method of each screen.

So, before you draw your new screen you have to use the function [Surface.fill](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html?highlight=fill#pygame.Surface.fill) (in your example, `self.background` is initialized as a Surface: `self.background = pygame.Surface((1275, 775))`).

The other screens will not be in the background of the current one, because Pygame only draws the one you are currently seeing.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on what you said. So is there any way I can delete this whole class? Because after pressing the space bar to start, I want the questions to begin right after. Instead of a blank page in between.

Comment: Pygame works on that way. To clean up the previous screen you have to draw something on the top of it. In this case you are filling the whole screen with a color.

Basically you have to say Pygame what do you want to draw. And if you already have something drawn, you will have to draw something over it to clean it up, you cannot remove it, you just draw over it.

Comment: So I filled the whole screen white, including the text and boxes. Now when I run the program, I press the space bar, a blank white screen is displayed (I have to click the page for it to move to the next scene), then the questions start. Can't you remove the SETTING scene in def main() ?

Comment: When I do the same, I see the blank white screen and the questions at the same time. I don't know if you want the questions to appear in the same screen or if you want them to appear in another screen like it's happening now?
Because I don't see the transition in 2 parts, first the white screen and then the questions, I see them at the same time.

Comment: Oh, could you share how you see both of the screens at the same time? Maybe I've done something wrong.

Comment: I don't see both screens at the same time. I see the transition smooth, I don't see the white background and then the questions. I see the white background and the questions appearing at the same time.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Could you show me how you've done it?

Comment: I didn't do anything besides copying your code and paste it. Maybe it's related to the computer processing power, I don't really know.
What I know is that what you are doing in your code is correct.

Comment: That's weird... Thank you for your help though. I have no idea why it's not working for me.

Answer (score -1):

normally in python you can unasign a variable with `del <name>`, at least you can in the version I use, Doing this in pygame. Would probably mess up some internal values, but you could probably fix this by quitting then reinitiating the display module.
I'm not sure this would work but this is what I would try.

Actually I would try to find a way to do what I wanted in one window, but you have probably got a good reason to want a new window.
Sorry if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Hey, everything is in one window, it just that if you run the code, there are different screens that appear. I'm trying to get rid of one of the scenes called the "difficulty screen" (it is displayed at the top of my question). If you have a solution to this please let me know. I've been struggling for a while now.